# Ubuntu 12.04 hanging problem while working

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04. Frequently Ubuntu hangs while working. If I try to work with open source software like GIMP and Skype then my system becomes hang. What should I do to Solve this problem?

My System configuration is:

```
Intel i3 processor
160GB HDD
2 GB DDR2 RAM
```

I'm using onboard graphics chipset. No external graphic card.

Comment: [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) is not [Free Open Source Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_Open_Source_Software)!

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
In place of <kbd>F1</kbd>, you can use: <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>

Now you can see command-line window.  To login enter the username and password, and then run:

```
 sudo restart lightdm
```

This trick restarts the display manager only, instead of a complete reboot you do by pressing reset button.

Comment: Thank you....but do you know any other way to stopped completely without hanging problem while working.i need more info

Answer (score 0):

[APK's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/366051/175814) is a good start.

Now if the X server isn't hanging but only the desktop compositor you can restart only the latter and possibly retain your session. First log in to your account from the command line. Depending on your compositor, run one of the following:

- Unity

  `DISPLAY=:0 setsid compiz --replace`
- Unity 2D

  `killall unity-2d-shell unity-2d-panel`
- Gnome Shell

  `DISPLAY=:0 setsid gnome-shell --replace`